# chart.Correlation independent vs dependent variables visualisation

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, correlation

In R, I have a dataset that has one independent variable and 9 dependent variables, and I want to see the scatter plot, histogram plus correlation values like in `chart.Correlation()` but I don't want to see the correlations between the dependent variables...as it is unnecessary.

I.e in the following mock example, I only care about/want to see the top row and to left most column, with all the histograms, with all the red lines and significance stars etc, BUT I don't care about/don't want all other other scatter plots and correlation values. Is this possible/is there a neat way of seeing all this in one visualisation...i.e. independent variable vs all dependent variables...?

mock example:

```
d <- xts(matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=10), Sys.Date()-1000:1)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
chart.Correlation(d)
```

On a side note...I am getting a bit annoyed by the font size of some of the correlation values produced from `chart.Correlation`... any way to set a minimum and maximum font size so that the font size doesn't become unreadable...

Also please feel free to use any other package (e.g. ggplot2 etc) that you think might be useful to help find a solution to the problem.

thanks in advance

EDIT:

So this is what I have come up with so far using `ggplot` and `plyr`...I'm still missing the histogram of the independent variable...oh and `multiplot` comes from here:  http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Multiple%20graphs%20on%20one%20page%20(ggplot2)/

and have now included it as answer...but any other suggestions/improvements would be well received....

```
require(plyr)
require(ggplot2)

indep.dep.cor <- function(xts.obj, title=""){

        # First column always assumed to be independent
        df <- data.frame(coredata(xts.obj))
        assign('df',df,envir=.GlobalEnv)

        df.l <- melt(df, id.vars=colnames(df)[1], measure.vars=colnames(df)[2:ncol(df)])
        assign('df.l',df.l, envir=.GlobalEnv)

        cor.vals <- ddply(df.l, c("variable"), summarise, round(cor(df[,1],value),3))
        stars <- ddply(df.l, c("variable"), summarise, symnum(cor.test(df[,1],value)$p.value, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " ")))
        cor.vals$stars <- stars[,2]
        assign('cor.vals',cor.vals,envir=.GlobalEnv)

        bin.w <- min((ddply(df.l,c("variable"),summarise,diff(range(value))/30))[,2])

        m1 <- ggplot(df.l,aes_string(x="value"))+
            facet_grid(.~variable)+
            stat_density(aes(y=..density..),fill=NA, colour="red", size=1.2)+
            geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),fill="white", colour="black", binwidth=bin.w)+
            opts(title=title)

        m2 <- ggplot(df.l,aes_string(x=colnames(df.l)[1], y="value"))+
            facet_grid(.~variable)+geom_point(aes(alpha=0.2))+
            opts(legend.position="none")+
            geom_text(data=cor.vals,aes(label=paste(cor.vals[,2],cor.vals[,3]),size=abs(cor.vals[,2])*2,colour=cor.vals[,2]),x=Inf,y=Inf,vjust=1,hjust=1,show_guide=FALSE)+
                scale_colour_gradient(low = "red", high="blue")+
                geom_smooth(method="loess")

        multiplot(m1,m2,cols=1)
}

indep.dep.cor(d)
```

Comment: oups forgot to add the package it was part of...i.e. PerformanceAnalytics...have now edited to include it in the question

Comment: Deleted earlier comment. Now. Please include library(plyr)  ... and nothing plots. What is `multiplots` supposed to do?

Comment: multiplot just puts two or more plots together in the same output

Comment: also for some reason in my example...it produces a nice density...but on my real data the histograms come up as counts rather than density...(depiste having a label as denisity but values as counts...weird)...i think some arguments need to be adjusted somehow...

Comment: also given that I have now amended the question feel that the downvote was a bit harsh...

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I have come up with so far using `ggplot` and `plyr`...I'm still missing the histogram of the independent variable...oh and `multiplot` comes from here:  http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Multiple%20graphs%20on%20one%20page%20(ggplot2)/

```
require(plyr)
require(ggplot2)

indep.dep.cor <- function(xts.obj, title=""){

        # First column always assumed to be independent
        df <- data.frame(coredata(xts.obj))
        assign('df',df,envir=.GlobalEnv)

        df.l <- melt(df, id.vars=colnames(df)[1], measure.vars=colnames(df)[2:ncol(df)])
        assign('df.l',df.l, envir=.GlobalEnv)

        cor.vals <- ddply(df.l, c("variable"), summarise, round(cor(df[,1],value),3))
        stars <- ddply(df.l, c("variable"), summarise, symnum(cor.test(df[,1],value)$p.value, corr = FALSE, na = FALSE, cutpoints = c(0, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 1), symbols = c("***", "**", "*", ".", " ")))
        cor.vals$stars <- stars[,2]
        assign('cor.vals',cor.vals,envir=.GlobalEnv)

        bin.w <- min((ddply(df.l,c("variable"),summarise,diff(range(value))/30))[,2])

        m1 <- ggplot(df.l,aes_string(x="value"))+
            facet_grid(.~variable)+
            stat_density(aes(y=..density..),fill=NA, colour="red", size=1.2)+
            geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..),fill="white", colour="black", binwidth=bin.w)+
            opts(title=title)

        m2 <- ggplot(df.l,aes_string(x=colnames(df.l)[1], y="value"))+
            facet_grid(.~variable)+geom_point(aes(alpha=0.2))+
            opts(legend.position="none")+
            geom_text(data=cor.vals,aes(label=paste(cor.vals[,2],cor.vals[,3]),size=abs(cor.vals[,2])*2,colour=cor.vals[,2]),x=Inf,y=Inf,vjust=1,hjust=1,show_guide=FALSE)+
                scale_colour_gradient(low = "red", high="blue")+
                geom_smooth(method="loess")

        multiplot(m1,m2,cols=1)
}

indep.dep.cor(d)
```